# How can i load data every time when an inner div of html page is changed?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my website i made a mainpage which has 3 divs: header, footer and main. Header div has some buttons which change main div. Means that page is loaded only once then i just change main div when some button is clicked. I simply put a html page in main div when some button is clicked.

i have put alert in every page's $(document).ready function. Whenever main div is changed, these alerts should come because main div is a html page. But these alerts are not coming. Why is that so. I want to load some data every time when main div is changed. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

main page:

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>    
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#btn1").click(function(){
                 $("#main").load("page1.html");
             });

             $("#btn2").click(function(){
                 $("#main").load("page2.html");
             });
         });
     </script>
</head>

    <body>
    <div id="header"> --- </div>
            <div id="maincontent"><div id="main"> --- </div></div>
            <div id="footer"> --- </div>
    </body> 
 </html>
```

page1:

```
  <html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>    
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             // trying to load data. but its not working
         });
     </script>
</head>

    <body>
    <div id="page1-div"> --- </div>

    </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: A sample page or code would be more than welcome.

Comment: How are you loading the content? Code would help.

Comment: code added. Please have a look.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just making changes in DOM, not loading new document which would trigger $(document).ready();.

Based in questions tags, i assume that you are loading content using AJAX. In that case just use jQuery's callbacks for $.ajax* functions to do any kind of action when content is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you need.
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/